# How can I extract part of an XML document using jquery to be transformed (xslt)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, extract

I want to know how can I extract part of an XML document using jquery to an object, which will be transformed via XSLT?  So, let's say I have this sample XML document:

```
<nutrition>

<daily-values>
    <total-fat units="g">65</total-fat>
<saturated-fat units="g">20</saturated-fat>
<cholesterol units="mg">300</cholesterol>
<sodium units="mg">2400</sodium>
<carb units="g">300</carb>
<fiber units="g">25</fiber>
<protein units="g">50</protein>
</daily-values>

<food>
<name>Avocado Dip</name>
<mfr>Sunnydale</mfr>
<serving units="g">29</serving>
<calories total="110" fat="100"/>
<total-fat>11</total-fat>
<saturated-fat>3</saturated-fat>
<cholesterol>5</cholesterol>
<sodium>210</sodium>
<carb>2</carb>
<fiber>0</fiber>
<protein>1</protein>
<vitamins>
    <a>0</a>
    <c>0</c>
</vitamins>
<minerals>
    <ca>0</ca>
    <fe>0</fe>
</minerals>
</food>

<food>
<name>Bagels, New York Style </name>
<mfr>Thompson</mfr>
<serving units="g">104</serving>
<calories total="300" fat="35"/>
<total-fat>4</total-fat>
<saturated-fat>1</saturated-fat>
<cholesterol>0</cholesterol>
<sodium>510</sodium>
<carb>54</carb>
<fiber>3</fiber>
<protein>11</protein>
<vitamins>
    <a>0</a>
    <c>0</c>
</vitamins>
<minerals>
    <ca>8</ca>
    <fe>20</fe>
</minerals>
</food>
</nutrition>
```

Let's say I just want the first < food >...< /food > block and I wish to save it as an object or a string.  How can this be done using jquery?  Once I have the XML block extracted, I can properly combine with a XSL document for transformation (XSLT).  Thank you very much for any help!

**UPDATE; CLARIFICATION:**

I apologize if my question is not clear.  Please allow me to clarify my position.

I am well aware that XML can be manipulated by using the browser's DOM and the differences between IE and non-IE implementations. I can use methods like cloneNode and selectNodes on an XML Object.  In fact, that's how I have done it.  Now if I bring jQuery into the equation, I'd like to replace all those lines of code with a **jQuery** way of dealing with it.  That is, perhaps there's a jQuery plugin that eliminates the need to directly interact with the XML DOM for each browser, taking care of cross-compatibility "behind-the-scenes".  I'm looking for a js framework that will take care of everything for me, instead of how I am dealing with it at the moment, which is separate implementations for IE and non-IE browsers.

I hope that clarifies my question.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears even those within the jQuery community recommend XML manipulation to be done by the browser, as it is usually faster.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery.parseXML(xmlString) you can convert an XML string to a
   jQuery object, then do whatever you want with that.

OR

If it's an XML file, you can GET it via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        error: function(){},
        success: function (xml) {// you can access the parsed XML just like you do it with HTML }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question.  I am aware that there are ways to manipulate the XML string/object using the browser's DOM.  What I want to know if jquery or a jquery plugin can do it for me, instead of the browser.

Comment: Yes, that is using jQuery to load the xml.  I understand that.  But that is not what I was looking for, unfortunately.  I am looking for JQuery/JQuery plugins to replace the need for using selectNodes,cloneNode, functions like that.  There doesn't appear to be a way in JQuery to take an XML object and extract a select block of it to a new XML object.

Answer (score 2):

In compatible browsers you can convert a document object or fragment to XML using an [*XMLSerializer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML):

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'div0'
var p = d.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d);

alert(xmlString); 
// shows <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="div0"><p></p></div>
```

A [little more work in IE](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/convert-xml-document-to-string-in-javascript), but not much. You need to create an XML object of just the bits you want, then get it's *xml* property:

```
alert(xmlObject.xml);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Yes, I have been able to take XML fragments by selecting nodes, without having to serialize it first.  What I wanted to know is if jquery has anything specific that does it for me, instead of the browser.  Thanks again.